# Find marginal PDF from joint PDF bound issue

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions

Given the joined density function for x and y is $$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{5}{16}{xy^{2}}$$ $$0<x<y,  0<y<2$$ find the marginal density function of Y.

I used: $$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{XY}(x,y) dx $$

$$=\int_0^2 \frac{5}{16}{xy^{2}} dx ​$$

but had a second thought about the bounds of x: should I use $\int_0^y$ instead of $\int_0^2$ since $0<x<y$? Why or why not? What is the standard approach/rules?

Comment: Are you sure you have the statement of the problem right? The integral of that pdf over the given bounds diverges.

Comment: Hi @JohnBarber, yes I think so; sorry what do you mean?

Comment: This pdf is not normalizable. In order for this to be a proper pdf, its integral over its domain must be 1.

Comment: @JohnBarber Sorry I just realised that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @nilsinelabore Are xou in the same class as the OP is this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4656302/144421) ?

Comment: @callculus42 Haha I think it was a coincidence but I don't think we are in the same class :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but had a second thought about the bounds of x: should I use $\int_0^y$ instead of $\int_0^2$ since $0<x<y$? Why or why not? What is the standard approach/rules?

Yes, you should use that, for that reason.  The joint pdf is only non-zero when $x$ is less than $y$.

You should also note the support for $Y$'s pdf.

$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases}\displaystyle\int_0^y \dfrac{5}{16xy^2}\,\mathrm d y &:& 0\leq y\leq 2\\[1ex] 0&:& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

**However** as @JohnBarber noticed, your given jpdf does not converge to one (or at all) over the given support.  I suspect a typo, as: $$\int_0^2\int_0^y\dfrac 5{16} x y^2 \,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y = 1$$

Comment: Hi Graham, thanks for your answer and for pointing out that typo!

Comment: As an additional question, to find $f_X(x)$ should I use (x,2) for the bounds of y then?

Comment: @nilsinelabore Exactly.